# Launcher tooltip display issues

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, icons, tooltip

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04.1, and it seems that I have some issues with the launcher: if I hover the mouse on an icon, it shows a horizontal line instead of the icon's name. If I hover it again, then it will show me the correctly displayed name, in label and all. The thing is pretty annoying. First hover no label (just that line), second hover, label.

Video drivers are installed. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a bug and hence off-topic for the site as per [Faq].

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [well-known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1034164) in Unity (the desktop environment Ubuntu uses by default). [A fix has been commited](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1034164/comments/44) and should soon arrive on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I've installed all the updates, but still this is happening here sometimes